# Photos not backed up to iCloud even though I have space

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, storage

My iPhone 11 says that 577 of my photos have not been uploaded to iCloud because there is not enough space.

However when I go to **Settings** > **iCloud** it says that I have only used 35.6 of 50 GB of the storage.

All of my other 1000 photos have uploaded but I don’t know why these are not.

Answer (score 1):

If your iPhone storage itself is full, it can stop the ability to upload to iCloud.

- Are your other devices able to upload new photos?
- Sign in-and-out of iCloud?
- Reboot the phone?
- Double check your wifi connection or enable uploading over cellular?

<sub>Source: [MacWorld](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/photos-not-uploading-icloud-3681817/)</sub>